# Sprite Kit - SKSpriteNode in weird positions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

I am trying to make a pong recreation, but it seems that the players (or paddles) and the balls are drawn in weird position for some reason.

Turning dynamic to false seems to work, but I definitely need it to be dynamic for the ball to bounce around the screen and for other physics to work

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0
    self.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = false
    self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0

    self.setUpPlayers()
    self.setUpBall()
}

func setUpPlayers() {
    p1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "racquet")
    p1.name = "p1"
    p1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height*0.1)
    p1.xScale = 1.5
    self.addChild(p1)

    p1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.frame.size)
    p1.physicsBody.dynamic = false
    p1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = pCategory
    p1.physicsBody.restitution = 0.1
    p1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    p1.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0
    p1.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0
    p1.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
    p1.physicsBody.friction = 0.4

    p2 = p1.copy() as SKSpriteNode
    p2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height*0.9)
    self.addChild(p2)
}

func setUpBall() {
    ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.frame.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0
    ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.0
    ball.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0
    ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0
    ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, p1.position.y+ball.frame.size.width/2+10)
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Expected result: [image]

Comment: Your code does explain the expected outcome, but could you show us how the sprites are actually being redered?

Comment: I'm not sure what is "weird" about this. Could you explain what it is you are expecting.